# Is there a word for a person who doesnt share much information?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word (adjective) to describe a man who is very sparing in his words and often unclear. He leaves few words to describe a requirement. Often he misses to put references and/or examples in order to better elicit what he wants - and he assumes we can read his mind.

Like concise - but without being clear :)

Comment: [synonym **tight-lipped**](https://www.google.com/search?q=synonym+tight-lipped&oq=synonym+tight-lipped&aqs=chrome..69i57.5679j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) *reticent, taciturn, uncommunicative, unforthcoming, unresponsive, close-mouthed, close-lipped, silent, quiet, unspeaking, guarded,...*

Comment: The first word that sprung to my mind was *taciturn*.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - for some reason the first word that sprung to my mind was _laconic_.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that sprung to my mind was [**elliptical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elliptical), which can mean:

> of, relating to, or marked by extreme economy of speech or writing
>
> of or relating to deliberate obscurity (as of literary or conversational style)

This adjective is usually applied to a particular speech, not to a person, so if you wanted to say that someone is always doing this, you could say something like,

> As usual, his explanation was so **elliptical** that it was incomprehensible.